# How to log the start time and the end time of each method in Android project?

Tags: android, performance, profiler

I need to generate the Call Graph of Android project.Are there any tools to log the start time and the end time of each method in Android project? I try traceview,it could show how long the method takes,but I can't find the start time and the end time.

Answer (score 1):

```
long startedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.d("ApplicationTag", "Started method X at time: " + startedAt);
...
long finishedAt = System.currentTimeMillis();
Log.d("ApplicationTag", "Finished method X at time: " + finishedAt + " after: " + (finishedAt-startedAt) + " milliseconds");
```